# VBScript: How to loop through multiple object properties and to pass object property as function parameter?

Tags: function, loops, vbscript, properties

I have three questions regarding VBScript:

1. How to loop through multiple object properties: .Lang, .Time, .Cal etc?
2. How to pass object with property or property as function parameter (see Function LoopThruAssocArrays(p_objArray1, p_arrArray1, p_objArray2, p_arrArray2))?
3. How to convert strObj string to object?

Goal is to set and read (log) followings objects iterating through properties, values and
Program.Settings.Numbers.Prec for each object variable. Any ideas how to release it in the most efficient manner? Regarding Q1 I've heard about reflection and class concept using Eval/Execute but honestly I do not know how to adopt it (I am not a programmer).

```
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Lang = U_Lang_en
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Lang = U_Lang_de
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Lang = U_Lang_es
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Lang = U_Lang_it
'...
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Time = U_Time_loc
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Time = U_Time_zon
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Time = U_Time_cet
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Time = U_Time_gmt
'...
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Cal = U_Cal_gre
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Cal = U_Cal_heb
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Cal = U_Cal_mus
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Regional.Cal = U_Cal_bud
'...
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Numbers.Prec = 0...3
'Set g_objProgram.Settings.Numbers.Delim = True/False ' not used yet
```

To store values Dictionary with arrays is used:

```
Function Code1 ()
Dim objSettingsRegional : objSettingsRegional ("Scripting.Dictionary")
objSettingsRegional ("Lang") = Array (U_Lang_en, U_Lang_de, U_Lang_es, U_Lang_it, ...)
objSettingsRegional ("Time") = Array (U_Time_loc, U_Time_zon, U_Time_cet, U_Time_gmt, ...)
objSettingsRegional ("Cal") = Array (U_Cal_gre, U_Cal_heb, U_Cal_mus, U_Cal_bud, ...)

arrSettingsNumbersPrec = Array (0,1,2,3)
arrSettingsNumbersDelim = Array (True, False)

For Each SettingsRegionalKey In objSettingsRegional.Keys
  For Each SettingsRegionalItem In objSettingsRegional.Items
     For Each SettingsNumbersPrecItem In arrSettingsNumbersPrecItem

       Dim strObj : strObj = "g_objProgram.Settings.Regional." & SettingsRegionalKey

       'converting string to obj???
       Dim objDict : objDict("Scripting.Dictionary")
       objDict. Add "StrToObj", strObj
       Dim item : item = objDictItem("StrToObj")

       Set item = SettingsRegionalItem
       Dim result1 : result1 = item

       Set g_objSettings.Numbers.Prec = SettingsNumbersPrecItem
       Dim result2 : result2 = g_objSettings.Numbers.Prec

     Next
  Next
Next
End Function
```

Other pseudo code example using arrays with multiple If...ElseIf statements:

```
Function Code2 ()
arrSettingsRegional = Array ("Lang", "Time", "Cal", ...)
arrSettingsRegionalLang = Array (U_Lang_en, U_Lang_de, U_Lang_es, U_Lang_it, ...)
arrSettingsRegionalTime = Array (U_Time_loc, U_Time_zon, U_Time_cet, U_Time_gmt, ...)
arrSettingsRegionalCal = Array (U_Cal_gre, U_Cal_heb, U_Cal_mus, U_Cal_bud, ...)

arrSettingsNumbersPrec = Array (0,1,2,3)
arrSettingsNumbersDelim = Array (True, False)

For Each SettingsRegionalKey In objSettingsRegionalKey
  If SettingsRegionalKey = "Lang" Then
    Dim strObj: strObj = "g_objProgram.Settings.Regional." & SettingsRegionalKey
    Call LoopThruAssocArrays (strObj, arrSettingsRegionalLang, objProgram.Settings.Numbers.Prec, arrSettingsNumbersPrec)
  ElseIf SettingsRegionalKey = "Time" Then
    strObj = "g_objProgram.Settings.Regional." & SettingsRegionalKey
    Call LoopThruAssocArrays (strObj, arrSettingsRegionalTime, g_objProgram.Settings.Numbers.Prec, arrSettingsNumbersPrec)
  ElseIf SettingsRegionalKey = "Cal" Then
    strObj = "g_objProgram.Settings.Regional." & SettingsRegionalKey
    Call LoopThruAssocArrays (strObj, arrSettingsRegionalCal, g_objProgram.Settings.Numbers.Prec, arrSettingsNumbersPrec)
  End If
Next

End Function

Function LoopThruAssocArrays(p_objArray1, p_arrArray1, p_objArray2, p_arrArray2)
  For Each p_arrArray1Item In p_arrArray1
    Set p_objArray1 = p_arrArray1Item
    Dim result1 : result1 = p_objArray1
      For Each p_arrArray2Item In p_arrArray2
        Set p_objArray2 = p_arrArray2Item
        Dim result2 : result2 = p_objArray2
      Next
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: **1.** Question doesn't make sense. **2.** You can only pass object variables or scalar variables. `x = Function(Object.Property)` passes the implicit scalar variable created by the return of `object.property`. **3.** Again doesn't make sense. Objects are CODE, strings have no code. In .NET they have string builder objects but normal basic doesn't as we have our own methods to do string building with scalar strings.

Comment: @Noodles I think they are referring to deserialising a `String` into an `Object`. In other words taking a string representation of an object and building an object from it.

Comment: Objects are CODE. They are not in and of themselves data. Though objects can persist by saving any data they get. But you need access to the code in a dll or exe. It's a aerie fairy question.

Comment: @Noodles what are you getting so worked up about? I really think you have got the wrong end of the stick with the question, granted it's not the greatest question in the world but neither is your reaction.

Comment: Could we focus on the solution? Some proposals with code? Thanks